# Create passport.js Oauth20 using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, passport-google-oauth

I have a working login feature and converting my login to a siginInWithGoogle feature in my flutter application using passport.js & googleOauth20.

I dont know how to call the `/google` callback URL and how to handle its responses. Can someone pls help me correct the dio call parameters to the API? Happy to provide more information. Thanks

This is how my `routes.ts` file looks like

```
router.post('/login', AuthController.login);
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'profile email' }));
router.get('/google/callback', AuthController.googleCallback);
```

my `auth.ts` file looks like

```
googleCallback: async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any> => {
    passport.authenticate(
      'google',
      { failureRedirect: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}?auth=social&responseType=error`, session: false },
      async (err, user) => {
        req.login(user, { session: false }, async (error) => {
          if (error) return next(error);

          const body = { _id: user._id, email: user.email };
          const token = jwt.sign({ user: body }, process.env.SECRET);

          const payload = {
            auth: 'social',
            responseType: 'success',
            provider: SocialProvider.Google,
            token,
          };
          const queryString = new URLSearchParams(payload).toString();
          return res.cookie('token', token).redirect(`${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/?${queryString}`);
        });
      }
    )(req, res, next);
  },
```

My dart class to sigin with google

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:ltp/utils/navigateFromResponse.dart';
import '../API/apiconstants.dart';

NavigateFromResponse navigateFromResponse = NavigateFromResponse();

ApiConstants apiConstants = ApiConstants();
Dio dio = Dio();

class SignInWithGoogleApi {

  Future siginwithgoogle() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.post(ApiConstants().baseURL + "google",
        options: Options(
            followRedirects: true,
            validateStatus: (status) {
              return status! <= 500;
            }
        ),
      );
      return response;
    }
    on DioError catch (dioError) {
      if (dioError.response!.statusCode == 401) {
        debugPrint(dioError.message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The onpressed function looks like

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => {
    setState((){
      isLoading = true;
    }),
    //loginApi.login(emailAddress, passWord).then((value) async =>
    googleApi.siginwithgoogle().then((value) async =>
    {
      if( value.statusCode == 200){
        profileInfoProvider.profileInfoProfileID(value.data["user"]["_id"]),
        profileInfoProvider.profileInfoToken(value.data["token"]),
        profileInfoProvider.profileInfoName(value.data["user"]["fullName"]),
        profileInfoProvider.profileInfoObject(value.data["user"]),
        profileInfoProvider.profileInitialAssign(value.data["user"]["fullName"]),
        profileInfoProvider.profileColorSet(randomNumber.nextInt(7)),
        channelApi.getAllChannels().then((value) async => {
                  channelProvider.channelListRefreshed(value.data),
                  setState((){
                    isLoading = false;
                  }),
                  Get.offAllNamed('/wrapper')
            }),
      }
      else{
        setState((){
          isLoading = false;
        }),
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              content: Text(
                'Invalid/Enter Credentials')))
        }
     }
  )
},
```

I am getting below error when I press the siginInWithGoogle button

```
`[GETX] NEW ROUTE null
Error: Unexpected null value.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 528:63  nullCheck
packages/ltp/API/sigininwithgoogle.dart 27:41                                     siginwithgoogle
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 60:31                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1658:54                                              runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:22                                        handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 778:46                                        handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 799:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 574:5                                         [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 51:12                                         [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 23:5                                          completeError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 617:44                                             onError
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1658:54                                              runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:22                                        handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 778:46                                        handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 799:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 574:5                                         [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 665:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15               <fn>`
```

Comment: I'm facing similar issues, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I simply moved my auth to firebase